# Group_concat distinct makes my query fails if the field is null

Tags: mysql, null, distinct, group-concat

```
SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(myValue)),',','|') FROM myTable WHERE myconditions
```

I'm using this query multiple times in a union. When myValue is different from NULL, it works. But when it has no value, the query fails (it says the query can't be executed). I tried to do IF(myValue IS NULL, '000', myValue), it doesn't work (Same for IFNULL). I think the distinct is what doesn't work here, since this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT('000') FROM myTable WHERE myconditions
```

doesn't work either.

How can I manage error for when myValue is null with a GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT())?

Thank you

Comment: Why not add a condition in the `where` clause like `where myValue is not null`

Comment: *"it says the query can't be executed"* doesn't sound like a MySQL error message.  What's the exact error? At any rate the data selected should not cause an error.  If you are using a really sad library to connect to MySQL, you may need to give the column an alias (`... AS somecolumnname FROM ...`).  Also, the syntax is documented as `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT expr)`, not `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(expr))`, though the extra parentheses might just be ignored, as they don't really modify `expr`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Mysql Query Browser says "The Query could not be executed" without any error number.
I know that it come from here because if I change my condition from "where id_client ='00001897'" to "where id_client='11111111'" it stops working.

Comment: @juergend where doesn't work, but having does. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(coalesce(myValue,'000'))),',','|') 
FROM myTable WHERE myconditions
```

Comment: With your sugggestion, my query works, but not in a union. I had to add a "Having <random_column_with_null_value_if_no_result> IS NOT NULL" for the union to work. Thanks!